# How do I add letters/phrases to the end of a string?

Tags: c#

I'm working on something simple, a Morse Code translator. I'm wondering how I can add letters to the end of a string, for example, '---' for 'O'

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/how-to-concatenate-multiple-strings You can just use the `+` operator to add strings together

Comment: Add in what context? To add to the end of a basic string, you literally just do `+=`. Considering you get plenty of examples just by googling "C# add strings" you should have **easily** been able to research this yourself.

Comment: Use +=. Use a StringBuilder. I really like giving answers, but this is a pretty simple subject. Perhaps try tutorialspoint.com initially for simple syntax "how-to" questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Dictionary<char, String> morseCode = new Dictionary<char, String>()
        {
            {'a' , ".-"},{'b' , "-..."},{'c' , "-.-."},
            {'d' , "-.."},{'e' , "."},{'f' , "..-."},
            {'g' , "--."},{'h' , "...."},{'i' , ".."},
            {'j' , ".---"},{'k' , "-.-"},{'l' , ".-.."},
            {'m' , "--"},{'n' , "-."},{'o' , "---"},
            {'p' , ".--."},{'q' , "--.-"},{'r' , ".-."},
            {'s' , "..."},{'t' , "-"},{'u' , "..-"},
            {'v' , "...-"},{'w' , ".--"},{'x' , "-..-"},
            {'y' , "-.--"},{'z' , "--.."},
            {'0' , "-----"},{'1' , ".----"},{'2' , "..----"},{'3' , "...--"},
            {'4' , "....-"},{'5' , "....."},{'6' , "-...."},{'7' , "--..."},
            {'8' , "---.."},{'9' , "----."},
        };

        string userText = "String To Test";

        userText = userText.ToLower();

        var sb = string.Empty; //var sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int index = 0; index < userText.Length; index++)
        {
            var t = userText[index];

            if (t != ' ')
            {
                string morseValue;

                if (morseCode.TryGetValue(t, out morseValue))
                {
                    sb += morseValue + " "; //or sb.Append(morseValue + " ");
                }
            }
            else {
                sb += "\n"; //or sb.Append("\n");
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sb); // or Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

I've shown you both examples. If you want test it try here:
http://rextester.com/OYGUG79820

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `+` operator on strings, which will concatenate them together:

```
var code = "...." + " " + ".."; // This will result in: ".... .."
```

For concatenating many strings, like in a loop where we are converting each character and appending it, using a `StringBuilder` is faster and uses less memory:

```
public static string MorseEncode(string inputString)
{
    if (inputString == null) return null;

    var codeBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (char input in inputString)
    {
        // Assuming you have a method to get the morse code for a char
        string encodedChar = GetMorseCode(input);  

        // Append our encoded char to our StringBuilder
        codeBuilder.Append(encodedChar);
    }

    // Return the String representation of our StringBuilder
    return codeBuilder.ToString();
}
```